# Is there a way to disable SSIS packages to read source data types?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

I'm trying to load an Excel file into SQL. The issue is with conversions.

I dont want to deal with conversions. I want to simply treat all columns as strings because they'll be dumped into a SQL table as strings.

What's the easiest way to get this to a SQL table without having to deal with all the conversion issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [MSDN entry for the Excel Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx) warns:

> The Excel driver reads a certain number of rows (by default, 8 rows) in the specified source to guess at the data type of each column. When a column appears to contain mixed data types, especially numeric data mixed with text data, the driver decides in favor of the majority data type, and returns null values for cells that contain data of the other type. (In a tie, the numeric type wins.)

Adding `IMEX=1` to the connection string puts the Excel source in "import mode"; columns with mixed data types in the first few rows will be treated as text data. However, there isn't any way to shut off the type-guessing "feature" of the Excel source; if those first few rows all contain numbers, the source **will** treat the column as numeric and force the conversions appropriately.

If you can convince whoever's supplying this file to send it to you in .CSV format, you can use a regular Flat File source to load it. Alternatively, you could configure a Script Component as a source and use the Excel object model to loop through the spreadsheet and spit out rows - but that won't qualify as "easy" unless you **really** know what you're doing.